# I cannot install MiKTeX 2.9 on windows 10

Tags: miktex, windows

I am installing MiKTeX on windows 10, the installer continue till the end then it stops, this is the log file

```
initializing setup service...
starting installer...
Loading package database...
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: "C:\Users\Osama\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9.5823"
package repository: C:\Users\Osama\AppData\Local\Temp\mik34770
visiting repository C:\Users\Osama\AppData\Local\Temp\mik34770...
repository type: local package repository
loading lightweight database...
lightweight database digest: 54ea0fa70d691728424e98e36c71a060
going to install 9891 file(s) (167 package(s))
extracting files from ae.tar.lzma...
extracting files from amscls.tar.lzma...
extracting files from amsfonts.tar.lzma...
extracting files from amsmath.tar.lzma...
extracting files from avantgar.cab...
extracting files from babel.tar.lzma...
extracting files from bidi.tar.lzma...
extracting files from bookman.cab...
extracting files from carlisle.tar.lzma...
extracting files from cbcoptic.tar.lzma...
extracting files from cm.tar.lzma...
extracting files from courier.tar.lzma...
extracting files from dehyph-exptl.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ec.tar.lzma...
extracting files from elhyphen.tar.lzma...
extracting files from enctex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from euenc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from eurosym.tar.lzma...
extracting files from float.cab...
extracting files from fontspec.tar.lzma...
extracting files from geometry.tar.lzma...
extracting files from graphics.tar.lzma...
extracting files from helvetic.cab...
extracting files from hyperref.tar.lzma...
extracting files from hyph-utf8.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ifxetex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from jknappen.cab...
extracting files from latex-fonts.tar.lzma...
extracting files from latex2e-help-texinfo.tar.lzma...
extracting files from lm.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ltxbase.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ltxmisc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from lua-alt-getopt.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luainputenc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from lualibs.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luamplib.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luaotfload.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luatexbase.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luatextra.tar.lzma...
extracting files from mflogo.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-arctrl-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-biber-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bibtex-base.cab...
extracting files from miktex-bibtex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bibtex8bit-base.cab...
extracting files from miktex-bibtex8bit-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-cairo-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-cjkutils-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-config-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-cweb-base.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-cweb-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-devnag-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dict-english.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dict-french.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dict-german.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-doc-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvicopy-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvipdfm-base-2.7.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvipdfmx-base-2.7.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvipdfmx-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvipng-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvips-base.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvips-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvips-doc.cab...
extracting files from miktex-dvisvgm-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-etex-base-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-findtexmf-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fontconfig-base.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fontconfig-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fontname-base.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fonts-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-freetype-base.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-freetype2-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-ghostscript-base-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-ghostscript-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-graphics-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-graphite2-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-gsf2pk-base.cab...
extracting files from miktex-gsf2pk-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-hunspell-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-hyph-french.tar.bz2...
extracting files from miktex-hyph-german.tar.bz2...
extracting files from miktex-hyph-usenglish.cab...
extracting files from miktex-icu-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-int-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-kpathsea-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-latex-config-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-log4cxx-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-lua52-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-luatex-base.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-luatex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-makeindex-base.cab...
extracting files from miktex-makeindex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-metafont-base.cab...
extracting files from miktex-metafont-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-metafont-misc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-metapost-base-2.7.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-metapost-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mft-base.cab...
extracting files from miktex-mfware-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-misc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mkfntmap-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mktex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mo-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mpm-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mpmcli-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mthelp-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mtprint-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-omega-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-pdftex-base-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-pdftex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-pdftex-doc-2.6.tar.bz2...
extracting files from miktex-poppler-base.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-poppler-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-ps2pk-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-psutils-base.cab...
extracting files from miktex-psutils-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-qt5-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-runtime-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-teckit-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex-base.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex-misc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex2xindy-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex4ht-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texify-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texinfo-base.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texware-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texworks-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texworks-doc-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-ttf2pk2-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-ucrt-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-vc120-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-vc140-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-web-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-xdvipdfmx-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-xetex-base.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-xetex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-xindy-base.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-xindy-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-yap-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-zip-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from multirow.cab...
extracting files from ncntrsbk.cab...
extracting files from oberdiek.tar.lzma...
extracting files from palatino.cab...
extracting files from pdftex-def.tar.lzma...
extracting files from pslatex.cab...
extracting files from psnfss.cab...
extracting files from pstricks.tar.lzma...
extracting files from rsfs.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ruhyphen.cab...
extracting files from tds.cab...
extracting files from thumbpdf.tar.lzma...
extracting files from times.cab...
extracting files from tools.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ukrhyph.cab...
extracting files from utopia.cab...
extracting files from xetexref.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xgreek.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xkeyval.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xltxtra.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xunicode.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xypic.tar.lzma...
extracting files from zapfchan.cab...
extracting files from zapfding.cab...
updating package definition directory ("C:\Users\Osama\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9.5823\tpm\packages")...
installed 2944 package definition files
visiting repository C:\Users\Osama\AppData\Local\Temp\mik34770...
repository type: local package repository
loading lightweight database...
66 [0x00000da0] INFO initexmf null - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5800 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
 81 [0x00000da0] FATAL initexmf null - --user-install=C:\Users\Osama\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9.5823: unknown option
  **Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed for the following reason: 
  --user-install=C:\Users\Osama\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9.5823: unknown option  You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help. 
Error: The executed process did not succeed.**
```

I tied on another windows 10 machine and I have the same result

Comment: I saw similar problems here: https://github.com/AnthonyMastrean/chocolateypackages/issues/143. Are you sure that LaTeX isn't working at all? Maybe just one package wasn't installed.

Comment: The "null" after initexmf looks odd. Perhaps the basic installer is not up-to-date. But most things seem to have been installed, so I would add first check what works and then check for updates (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108447/how-should-one-maintain-and-update-a-miktex-installation/108490#108490).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, When I open the TeXstudio it tells me that "No LaTeX distribution was found on your system"

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I downloaded the installer from the original site http://www.miktex.org/download, version 2.9.5823 which is the latest one as found in the site.

Comment: Delete Windows 10, install a linux and this will solve the problem.

Comment: Had the same issue with new Windows 10. In my case, apparently you cannot _rename_ the installation file. (See link given by Dr. Manuel Kuehner). Nothing else helped - with/without admin rights, changing temp directories, installing to a new partition etc.

Answer (score 2):

go into windows defender add the directory where you are installing as not to be scanned the run as admin should install

Comment: this solved my problem too. I got permission denied message. Then just to give it a try, I added 'C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9' folder to exclude list from settings. Everything worked perfect after that. Apparently, windows defender considers copy_start.exe as some malicious program and blocks it.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I stopped my McAfee antivirus/firewall, but it didn't help.

What I did was that I moved MiKTeX and it's installer to another partition (other than my windows one), and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's an antivirus/firewall blockage issue. In my case I stopped all antivirus protections temporarily and it passed. I had tried it before multiple times and it always ended in error. In the logs the message I had was a permission denied.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I just solved my problem, I´m hoping this works for you too.
Find an application called MiKTeX Settings (I found it clicking on the windows start button and finding it in "All programs")
Go to the packages tab an tick SGML/XML/HTML. Now go into the General tab and make sure Install missing packages on the fly is set to No. Then click the refresh FNDB button. And then apply the settings.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I searched for it in the start menu and I found nothing related to MiKTeX.

Comment: How can you find a software option if the software is not installed?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem appeared to be with the `Temp` directory for which the installer could not get access for some reason on a clean Windows 10 installation. The following commands in the elevated command prompt helped (I created `C:\Tools\temp` directory first):

```
set TEMP=C:\Tools\temp
set TEMPDIR=C:\Tools\temp
set TMP=C:\Tools\temp
setup-2.9.6300-x64.exe
```

P. S.: The same problem appeared to be with MiKTeX Update (Admin). So I had to change permanently `TEMP` and `TMP` environment variables for the current user to `C:\Tools\temp`.

P. P. S.: Later, the same problem with a new `Temp` folder arised again. It looks like it could be fixed with cleaning the contents of `Temp`. If, after that, there are still files remaining that are locked by other applications, creating a new `Temp` folder and pointing `TEMP` and `TMP` environment variables to it helps.

Comment: In several contexts (MiKTeX is not alone) I have noticed the temp directory permission problem. Goes back to Windows 7, I believe. Probably has to do with the installer, rather than the program being installed. As you noted, manipulating the required temp directory (whatever it is) often helps.